# Ошибка string subscript out of range в цикле for

Tags: c++

У меня есть две строки: text и symbols. **В строке text уже сохранён некоторый текст.** Первое слово этого текста: "Classification". Вообще в тексте больше 1500 символов. Моя задача поместить в строку symbols все символы, которые встречаются в text, но в единичном экземпляре, т.е. просто набор символов. Я написал for с кучей условий для проверки. Благодаря шагу в visual studio смог обнаружить, что ошибка возникает на втором проходе цикла, т.е. когда *text[1] = 'l'*. Ошибку выбивает на строке **symbols[j] = text[i];**

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ifstream file4("E:\\text4.txt");
    if (!file4)
    {
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    char s;
    int size = 0;
    while (!file4.eof()) //Выяснили размер текста
    {
        file4.get(s);
        size++;
    }
    file4.close();
    file4.open("E:\\text4.txt");
    int i = 1, k = 1, j, k_new;
    string text;
    string symbols;
    while (!file4.eof())
    {
        file4.get(s);
        text = text + s;
    }
    file4.close();
    symbols += text[0];
    for (i; i < size; i++) {                  // цикл для прохождения всего текста
        j = k - 1;                            // обновляем переменные, т.к. они были изменены
        k_new = k;                            // j: для проверки элементов symbols, k_new (размер symbols): для цикла ниже
            for (k_new; k_new > 0; k_new--) { // проводится цикл для всех элементов symbols
                if (text[i] != symbols[j]) {  // проверка на равенство данного символа элементу symbols
                    if (j != 0) {             // проверка для остановки цикла
                        j--;                  // уменьшаем j для проверки предыдущего элемента symbols
                    }
                    else {                    // если были проверены все эелменты symbols
                        symbols += text[i];   // добавляем символ в строку symbols
                        k++;                  // увеличиваем k (размерность symbols)
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {                        // если найден такой же символ в symbols
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    cout << symbols << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Если у вас строка `symbols` пустая, то вы проверяете почему-то `symbols[0]`. Там и ошибка. Проверять сначала нужно, что `k==0` (символов ещё нет). А лучше сразу первый символ завести без условий. Индекс `k` - очень расплывчатое название. Цель у это переменной какая?

Comment: @AlexGlebe я использовал k для сравнения данного элемента строки text с каждым элементом строки symbols. Сначала я использовал вместо k -> j, но потом понял, что j изменяется, а мне этого не нужно, поэтому и создал k. Присвоить сразу первый элемент это хорошая идея, я даже и не подумал об этом.

Comment: Символы нужно **добавлять** в строку, а не присваивать в неизвестное место `symbols[0] = text[0];`. Например так, `symbols += text[0];` И логику бесконечного добавления куда-то не могу никак понять. `{
                    symbols[k] = text[i];
                    k++;
                }`

Comment: @AlexGlebe теперь этой ошибки не выдаёт, правда в symbols хранится не совсем то, что нужно, ибо при размере текста в 1500+ символов выводит: _Clasifcton dPre
3.1Dg_

Comment: @AlexGlebe k - кол-во элементов строки symbols для фора

Comment: Вы своим сравнением с первым символом останавливаете весь процесс. Цикл останавливается здесь `if (text[i] == text[0])
        {
            break;
        }`. Уберите этот `if` - он портит прогу. Напишите сначала алгоритм словами: ищу записанные буквы, и если не нашёл, то добавляю.

Comment: @AlexGlebe огромное спасибо, изменил как Вы сказали и всё заработало: выводит больше 50 символов. Всё равно не понимаю почему то условие ломало код, но теперь всё нормально! Как я могу вас отметить?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас строка symbols пустая, то вы проверяете почему-то `symbols[0]`. Там и ошибка. Проверять сначала нужно, что `k==0` (символов ещё нет). А лучше сразу первый символ завести без условий.

---

Символы нужно добавлять в строку, а не присваивать в неизвестное место `symbols[0] = text[0];`. Например так, `symbols += text[0];`

---

Вы своим сравнением с первым символом останавливаете весь процесс. Цикл останавливается здесь `if (text[i] == text[0]) { break; }`. Уберите этот `if` - он останавливает цикл просмотра строки. Напишите сначала алгоритм словами: ищу записанные буквы, и если не нашёл, то добавляю.